# Restore fedora 25 repolist

Tags: fedora, upgrade, repository, dnf

Rawhide was causing troubles, so I decided to remove it, I backed up my original repo list names. The original repo list looked like that

```
fedora-cisco-openh264.repo   rpmfusion-free.repo
fedora-rawhide.repo          rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
fedora.repo                  rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
fedora-spotify.repo          rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide.repo
fedora-updates.repo          rpmfusion-nonfree.repo
fedora-updates-testing.repo  rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
google-chrome.repo           rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo
rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo
```

I removed few of them, thinking that by removing rawhide and testing repos, my system would only search for stable packages. By removing, I mean that I did `rm /etc/yum.repos.d/repo` and then `dnf clean all`, no other commands. My new repo list is:

```
fedora-cisco-openh264.repo  rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
fedora.repo                 rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
fedora-spotify.repo         rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide.repo
fedora-updates.repo         rpmfusion-nonfree.repo
google-chrome.repo          rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
rpmfusion-free.repo         rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo
```

Now, I can't do `sudo dnf update`, nor `sudo dnf reinstall fedora-release`. I get this error `Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora'kB/s | 491 kB     41:01 ETA`

My questions are:

- Which repo I need to restore and how to restore it?
- Are there any testing repos I can safely remove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a proper way of removing repositories, usually repositories comes from packages, so removing a repository is a matter of finding package it belongs to.

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/repository.repo
```

If repository file is belonging to some package upper command will tell what that package is.

Secondly, there is no need to remove anything, repositories can be disabled. You can use following command to tell what repositories are currently enabled.

```
$ sudo dnf repolist
```

You can use following command to disable a repository.

```
$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled <repository>
```

Part to your question, that error message has nothing to do with missing repositories, and has something to do with network (dns, cache etc.).

Bare minimum repositories you should have enabled are `fedora` and `fedora-updates`.

Comment: ok so how to solve/debug the problem I'm having?

Comment: Try to access URL directly e.g. from:
`$ fgrep '[fedora]' -A10 /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo | grep metalink
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch`

Enter into your browser something like:
https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-25&arch=x86_64 .

You should get a file with a list of repositories, try to see if they work in the same way.

Comment: @srakitnican i keep getting `No such file or directory. bash: arch‌​=: command not found...`

Comment: @sourcejedi If repository file is deleted, it will just be recreated with another update, disabling it on the other hand or modifying it will be respected by package manager. Package manager will create new configuration file with rpmnew extension in that case.

Comment: @Lynob My lines were all combined in comments, use following command:
`fgrep '[fedora]' -A10 /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo | grep ^metalink`. Then replace `$releasever` and `$basearch` from link with a proper values for your machine, for example `25` and `x86_64`.

Comment: I run the command correctly and from the browser I can see that i got the correct xml file but from terminal if I run `fgrep '[fedora]' -A10 /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo | grep metalink metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-25&arch=x86_64` I see  `fedora-25 no file or directoty.` Strange!

Comment: So in that xml file should be a list of mirrors that you can try to browse and see if they work for you. This list is generated dynamically based on various parameters like location. There might be a problem with a bad mirror (files missing).

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank *srakitnican* for indicating that it's an error related to the mirrors. I ended up fixing it by adding `fastestmirror=1` to `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`. I'm going to accept his answer because his efforts helped me solve the issue.